# How to open an options menu from a non-actionbar button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

I want to open an options menu from another button, not from an actionbar button, like so:

[image: My idea]

How can I make a menu show up on a button like this?

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for can be done using a `PopupMenu` object.

You can look at these simple examples: 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android-popup-menu-example 
or 
https://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example

There are many other examples on the Web and YouTube.